# Как сделать форму обратной связи с загрузкой нескольких изображений?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Саму форму и загрузку нескольких изображений я делаю так:

```css
#feedback-form {
  /* вся форма */
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
#feedback-form label {
  /* наименование полей */
  float: left;
  display: block;
  clear: right;
}
#feedback-form .w100 {
  /* поля */
  float: right;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 97%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1.5%;
}
#feedback-form .border {
  /* граница полей */
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #C0C0C0 #D9D9D9 #D9D9D9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #abd9f1 #bfe3f7 #bfe3f7;
}
#feedback-form .border:hover {
  border-color: #7eb4ea #97cdea #97cdea;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  /* убрать при фокусе первоначальный текст поля */
  color: transparent;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
#feedback-form .border:not(:focus):not(:hover):valid {
  /* правильно заполненные поля */
  opacity: .8;
}
#submitFF {
  /* кнопка "Отправить" */
  padding: 2%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset;
  background: #669acc;
  color: #fff;
}
#feedback-form br {
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
#submitFF:hover {
  background: #5c90c2;
}
#submitFF:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="feedback-form">
  <label for="nameFF">Имя:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nameFF" id="nameFF" required placeholder="например, Иван Иванович Иванов" x-autocompletetype="name" class="w100 border">
  <label for="contactFF">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="contactFF" id="contactFF" required placeholder="например, ivan@yandex.ru" x-autocompletetype="email" class="w100 border">
  <label for="fileFF">Прикрепить файл:</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" class="w100">
  <label for="messageFF">Сообщение:</label>
  <textarea name="messageFF" id="messageFF" required rows="5" placeholder="Детали заявки…" class="w100 border"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input value="Отправить" type="submit" id="submitFF">
</form>
```

Код contacts.php:

```html
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['contactFF'])) {
  $to = "name@yandex.ru";
  $from = $_POST['contactFF'];
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail: ".$from."\nIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF'];
  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
         $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
         $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
     }
   }
   $message.="
--$boundary--";

  if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
}
?>
```

Мне необходимо чтобы была последовательная загрузка изображений с превью, как здесь (кликнуть на + и загружать следующее изображение):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень надеюсь на помощь. Может есть готовые решения или примеры..

Answer (score 0):

Почитай о [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), в руководстве mozilla все отлично написано, собственно пример коротко

```
var form = document.getElementById("feedback-form");
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "contacts.php");
xhr.send(new FormData(form));
```

Получить привьюшки можно при помощи объекта [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader) перехватив действие change у `<input type="file" >`

Ну и еще ты спрашивал библиотеки, их так много что не перечесть, [например](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Comment: Да, только что тоже нашел dropzone, только вот не знаю, как связать его с формой отправки. Можешь подсказать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Если ты хочешь отсылать все данные скопом то лучше сделай через FormData, она сразу все заберет и отправит, а через dropzone там есть события например `var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
  myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
  });` там есть список событий , тебе например может понадобиться success, тогда дождался когда твой файлы загрузились куда надо, и возвращай их имена, имена клади в hidden поля в форму, когда отправишь будешь знать какие фото к какой форме, но это гемор